# Display hierarchy of selected object only

Tags: python, hierarchy, maya

I am creating a UI where the user selects an object,
the UI will display its hierarchy of the selected
object.
It is somewhat similar to Outliner but I am unable to
find any documentation/ similar results to what I am
trying to obtain. And btw, I am coding using python...

Even so, is this even possible to do it in the first
place?

Allow me to provide a simple example below:
Say if I selects testCtrl, it will only displays
testCtrl, loc and jnt without showing the Parent (Grp 01)

Eg. Grp 01 --> testCtrl --> loc --> jnt

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def customOutliner():
if cmds.ls( sl=True ):
    # Create the window/UI for the custom Oultiner 
    newOutliner = cmds.window(title="Outliner (Custom)", iconName="Outliner*", widthHeight=(250,100))
    frame = cmds.frameLayout(labelVisible = False)
    customOutliner = cmds.outlinerEditor()

    # Create the selection connection network; Selects the active selection
    inputList = cmds.selectionConnection( activeList=True )
    fromEditor = cmds.selectionConnection()

    cmds.outlinerEditor( customOutliner, edit=True, mainListConnection=inputList )
    cmds.outlinerEditor( customOutliner, edit=True, selectionConnection=fromEditor )

    cmds.showWindow( newOutliner )

else:
    cmds.warning('Nothing is selected. Custom Outliner will not be created.')
```

Answer (score 3):

### Make the window:

You want to use the `treeView` command ([documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/treeView.html)) for this. I'm placing it in a formLayout for convenience.

```
from maya import cmds
from collections import defaultdict

window = cmds.window()
layout = cmds.formLayout()

control = cmds.treeView(parent=layout)

cmds.formLayout(layout, e=True, attachForm=[(control,'top', 2),
                                            (control,'left', 2),
                                            (control,'bottom', 2),
                                            (control,'right', 2)])
cmds.showWindow(window)
```

### Populate the tree view:

For this, we'll use a recursive function so you can build up the hierarchy with nested `listRelatives` calls ([documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/listRelatives.html)). Start with the result of old faithful `ls -sl`:

```
def populateTreeView(control, parent, parentname, counter):
    # list all the children of the parent node
    children = cmds.listRelatives(parent, children=True, path=True) or []

    # loop over the children
    for child in children:
        # childname is the string after the last '|'
        childname = child.rsplit('|')[-1]

        # increment the number of spaces
        counter[childname] += 1
        # make a new string with counter spaces following the name
        childname = '{0} {1}'.format(childname, ' '*counter[childname])

        # create the leaf in the treeView, named childname, parent parentname
        cmds.treeView(control, e=True, addItem=(childname, parentname))

        # call this function again, with child as the parent. recursion!
        populateTreeView(control, child, childname, counter)


# find the selected object
selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]

# create the root node in the treeView
cmds.treeView(control, e=True, addItem=(selection, ''), hideButtons=True)

# enter the recursive function
populateTreeView(control, selection, '', defaultdict(int))
```

### Comparison of window to outliner.

I've replaced the spaces with `X` so you can see what's happening. Running this code will use spaces though:

[image]

---

You'll want to read up on the documentation to improve on this, but this should be a great starting point. If you want a live connection to the selection, make a `scriptJob` to track that, and be sure to clear the treeView before repopulating.

Comment: Your coding may be the one I am looking for, however pardon me but based on the Pic you have provided, is there any way possible to omit out some of the namespace?
Eg. group8|group3, can I omit omit out group8?

Comment: I see, hmm... I can somewhat foreseen that my UI is going to be different from what I imagined... Thank you.

Comment: Noted about that. Just thought that there may be a function somewhere in Maya that deals with it.

Comment: Thanks alot. In the meantime, I shall do some research of my own as well.

Comment: Will read that up. By the way, could I ask from your coding, which line executes the part where it displays the Shape? I tried to modify some parts of your code but whenever I did so, it totally screws up the results....

Comment: I've edited my question with a better and more documented answer

Comment: I have add in a code in my first post but I would like to know if the code I have put up, is it feasible enough? Truth to be told, I am merely reusing and edit bit and pieces of information that I have derived the example from the Maya documentation

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that was possible. How do you mean "feasible"? It certainly looks like it's working. You should make that an answer to your own question and accept it for future visitors to find

Comment: My bad cause I am not sure if it can be considered an answer in the first place... By feasibility I would says if it is good enough to cater or tackle upcoming problems.. Apparently I am seeing the problem that it is unable to store the current selection should the selection be empty

Comment: Consider asking about that issue as a new question instead then

Comment: Sure will do. Perhaps I will try and see if I am able to figure it out. Thanks!